# Spring-Data/HQL: How to create a current_timestamp in query from LocalDate and LocalTime property

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Sorry for this strange title; don't know how to describe this really. Feel free to suggest a correction :-)

In my JPA Entity im having the following properties (startTime is nullable):

```
private LocalDate startDate;
private LocalTime startTime;
```

Is it possible to build a query which can compare a given LocalDateTime with these two properties but combined or build/create a timestamp consisting of these two separated properties on the fly?

```
@Query( "SELECT t FROM Test t " +
        "WHERE " +
            "t.id = :testId " + 
            "AND ( " + 
                "t.startDate >= current_date() " + 
                "AND (t.startTime IS NULL OR t.startTime >= current_time()) " + 
            ")")
public Page<Test> findBySomething(@Param("testId") Long testId, Pageable pageable);
```

... this one of course doesn't work as it compares it separated.

What im looking for is something like

```
...AND new DatabaseDateOrWhatEver(t.startDate, t.startTime) >= current_timestamp...
```

Im using latest versions of postgresql and spring data/-jpa.

Comment: Just to clarify : you want to compare given LocalDateTime with 2 attributes of your entity and get to know whether Date attribute value and Time attribute value is within given LocalDateTime?

Comment: Either this or to use the current_timestamp function if to compare with "now" which would be equivalent to LocalDateTime.now()

Comment: What is the precision for fractional seconds for `current_timestamp` in your system?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [JPQL Datetime Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_datetime):

> functions_returning_datetime:= CURRENT_DATE | CURRENT_TIME | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
>
> The datetime functions return the value of current date, time, and timestamp on the database server.

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Test t WHERE t.id = :testId AND ( " + 
                "t.startDate >= current_date " + 
                "AND (t.startTime IS NULL OR t.startTime >= current_time))")
```

Comment: This IS what im using already but it doesnt work. Imagine a record with a date of tomorrow and a time of 5am. If you would do a search now you wouldn't get this record if your local time would be <= 5am even if your date is in the future. Hope i could explain the problem...

Comment: @StephanM You need to compare with session time or db time?

Comment: Can't you compare for both date and time combined like `(t.startDate >= current_date AND t.startTime >= current_time)`. First condition will short-circuit if date is not today's.